# Grails log configuration is hijacking the external log configuration, how to stop it?

Tags: java, grails, logging, configuration

I have a web application consisting of severals modules. All the modules are packaged together in one single ear.
One of them is a brand new groovy app, while others are more old school.  This new grails app is not under my responsibility.
Notice that grails is not using any log4j.[properties|xml] file, but it as its own DSL which interact directly with log4j at runtime. This configuration is located inside a config.groovy script, packaged with the application.

Log4j is configured using an external file and the -Dlog4j.configuration option for the JVM.

The problem is the grail configuration is containing a very liberal config:
 - set the root level to info
 - add a console appender

The result is that the external configuration is hijacked by grails:
now there are two console appender (logging twice the same info) and lots of useless info data are logged.

Is there another solution than a programmatic approach, to tell grails to stop being rude ?

Comment: Configure it in the Grails log config file.

Comment: the grails app is a sub module, packaged in a jar. I don't want to have to change this config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just turn off the grails logging so it uses the external logger

http://blog.saddey.net/2010/02/07/grails-how-to-use-native-server-logging-configuration-eg-tomcat-glassfish-jboss/

Comment: Thanks a lot Tomas. I'm just disappointed by the fact that there is no external to tell to grails to stop using built-in logs... The procedure found on the is very hacky and you need to add support for it inside the grails app: I'll need to ask to the groovy dev team for these changes : this is not really dev friendly :( But I guess this is the only way to proceed.